# How to serialize data and fix the wrong one in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, serialization

I'm new to Python. I need to serialize the data by the first two chars is taken from the first and the last char in the given string plus the transposed number just like this one:

```
Input: ["HOMAGE", "DESIGN", "PROTECTION", "COMPANY"]
Output: ["HE01", "DN02", "PN03", "CY04"]
```

Below is my current code:

```py
ls = ["HOMAGE", "DESIGN", "PROTECTION", "COMPANY"]
ser = []

def serialize(lis):
    for l in range(len(lis)):
        ser = lis[l] + str(l)
        return ser

result = serialize(ls)
print(result)
```

I've tried to dissect the array but nothing else solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `list comprehension approach`:

```
ls = ["HOMAGE", "DESIGN", "PROTECTION", "COMPANY"]
ser = [f"{j[0]}{j[-1]}{i+1:>02}" for i,j in enumerate(ls)]
print(ser)
```

**What did I do above?**

- Using `f-strings` makes it easier to create strings with variables.
  `enumerate(iterable)` returns the `(index, value)` pair of the iterable.
- `j[0]` and `j[-1]` are nothing but the first and last values.
- `i+1:>02` returns the `index` with a preciding 0. i.e `1` returns `01`.
- `+1` since you don't want `00` as the first but `01`.

**Edit:** Thanks to @ILS
You could also omit `+1` and directly start `enumerate()` with 1

```
ser = [f"{j[0]}{j[-1]}{i:>02}" for i,j in enumerate(ls, 1)]
```

**Docs:**
[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
[`String Formatting`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting)
[`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: `enumerate` can start from a specified number.

Comment: @ILS I know, but I don't see any problem in doing `+1`. Just an easy approach.

Comment: Yes, no problem. Just a bit redundant. Leave it as you like. :)